# Cards fill out container in mobile

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

So Im using Bootstrap 4 "alpha3". I like the setup that I have for desktop but Im having an issue when going down to mobile. There is some space between the cards and the end of the container on desktop and thats fine. But what I want is when I go to mobile I want the width of the cards to take up the entire container. This is my scss for my posts

```
@media screen and (min-width: 34em) {
.posts.index .card {
 height: 425px;
 width: 100%;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
.posts.index .card {
height: 430px;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 75em) {
.posts.index .card {
height: 440px;
 }
}
```

This is my card index.html.erb

```
 <div class= 'col-lg-6'>
  <div class="card">
    <%= link_to post do %>
  <div class="card-topper" style='background-image: url(<%= post.banner_image_url %>);'></div>
   <% end %>
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h4>
    <h6 class="published-date"><%= post.display_day_published %></h6>
    <%= link_to post do %>
    <p class="card-text"><%= truncate(post.description, length: 130) %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

So again Im trying to have the cards fill out the container width on the smaller screens (mobile).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to remove `padding` on small screens, and by small you mean less than `34em`. In that case, add this code:

```
@media (max-width: 34em) {
  .col-lg-6 {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
  }
}
```

PS: I wouldn't recommend to mess with BS classes, so it's better to make additional class, like `no-padding-sm`, and add this class to your `col-lg-6` div